# Search Array and increment element if ID matches

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to increment the `productQuantity` of an item that has been pushed into an array. If the `productID` of the item matches that of an item already in the array, the quantity should be increased.

```
  export function ADD_ITEM(state, product) {
      //  state.isAdded = true;
      const added = state.storeCart.find(product => product === 
       product.productID)
      if (!added) {
        state.storeCart.push(product)
      } else {
        product.productQuantity++
      }
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Is the issue that you should be doing `state.storeCart.push(product)`?

Comment: When I try to add an item with the same ID, it's added as a new entry

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few issues.

1. The `product` argument in your `find` callback function is shadowing the `product` argument from the `ADD_ITEM` function. We'll change this to `p`.
2. In the `find` callback, you should check if the `productID` of `p` is equal to that of the provided `product`.
3. It seems that you just want to `push` the entire `product` onto the `storeCart`, not push each individual property.
4. You should increment `productQuantity` on `added` since that's a ref to the actual existing item in state.

```
export function ADD_ITEM(state, product) {
  const added = state.storeCart.find(p => p.productID === product.productID);
  if (!added) {
    state.storeCart.push(product);
  } else {
    added.productQuantity++;
  }
}
```

Just to demonstrate that this is functional, here's a bare-bones example.

```js
function ADD_ITEM(state, product) {
  const added = state.storeCart.find(p => p.productID === product.productID);
  if (!added) {
    state.storeCart.push({...product});
  } else {
    added.productQuantity++;
  }
}

const state = {
  storeCart: []
}

const hat = { productID: 1, name: "hat", productQuantity: 1 };
const jacket = { productID: 2, name: "jacket", productQuantity: 1 };
const shoes = { productID: 3, name: "shoes", productQuantity: 1 };

ADD_ITEM(state, hat);
ADD_ITEM(state, jacket);
ADD_ITEM(state, shoes);
ADD_ITEM(state, jacket);

console.log(state);
```

Comment: When I try to push specific elements in `product`, I get a list of invisible items just from one product added.

Comment: While you are still available, how will I get the `totalPrice` of all the items in `state.storeCart`?

Comment: You could use the `reduce` array method. `const totalPrice = state.storeCart.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.price * el.productQuantity, 0)`

Comment: I had to modify `el.price` to `el.unitPrice` to get my total. Thanks!